# resizing effect on TitleWindow Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, resize

I would like to know how I can add maximize and restore functionalities to a Flex TitleWindow.
I used something like this 
`<s:Button label="maximize panel" click="Panel1.height = 300;Panel1.width = 300"/>`
`where Panel1 is the id for TitleWindow` but there was not effect for it.

I would also like to know how to add buttons on the titlewindow title( so that I can include buttons for maximize and minimize).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple actually:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:Resize id="ohyea" widthTo="300" heightTo="300" duration="500" target="{Panel1}"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:Button label="maximize panel" click="ohyea.play();"/>
```

You can do the same thing in the title window, just change the target to "this".

Comment: thanks for the reply.. thats the same thing I did.. could you tell me how can I add that button to the titlewindow title bar?

Comment: Create a skin file and set the "skinClass" property of your title window. In the skin file created by copying the default spark skin on line 249 you can see the "close button" defined, simply define a few more buttons here and you can do the actions right in the skin file.

Comment: another thing.. once I created my own skin class, how do I apply it to my titleWindow? do I just include it in the application tag as skinClass="location\createdSkin" ?

Comment: yes, except you need to use dot notation instead of a path because it is a "class". `skinClass="location.createdSkin"`

Comment: yeah.. thanks.. I got that working.. one last thing.. now that I have added a button, how do I call it? because for the close button, there was a "close" which we could use to call a close handler.. how do I do it for the button I created in the skin?